# Threshold limit problem

Tags: development

I am using the following Query to retrieve the latest documents of the current user:

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='FSObjType'></FieldRef>
            <Value Type='Text'>0</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Or><Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Author' />
                <Value Type='Integer'><UserID/></Value>
            </Eq> 
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Editor'/>
                <Value Type='Integer'><UserID/></Value>
            </Eq>
        </Or>

            </And>
</Where>
<OrderBy>
 <FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE"/>
</OrderBy>
```

It is failing if the total number of documents in the site collection is higher than the threshold limit, even if the return result of the above query is only a few documents.

How to change the above query so that i don't risk exceeding the threshold.

Example, user1 has changed 5 documents in a list that contains 7000 documents. i want to display those 5 documents using the above query. If the list threshold is less than 7000, i get an exception. How to change the above query so not to exceed the threshold limit?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure there's a rowLimit to apply. You should be able to add this using this element in CAML

```
<RowLimit>10</RowLimit>
```

You can see how to apply this on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee534956.aspx).

**EDIT:**

Per your comment below, I think perhaps the [ContentIterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798376.aspx) is more what you need (code sample included). This should allow you to iterate over each matching item.

Comment: I believe rowlimit will execute after getting the result, which has  no effect, no?

Comment: I suspect you're right. I'll share other thoughts in a different answer.